# Error for importing function in another module

Tags: python-3.x

I have a helper function defined as follows:

```py
def get_the_MC_list(path):
    find_list = ["MC*.jpg"]
    filenames = get_the_jpgs(path)
    MC_list = []
    for filename in filenames:
        if any(fnmatch(filename, pattern) for pattern in find_list):
            MC_list.append(filename)
    return MC_list
```

I call this routine to get the *`"MC.jpg"`* files from a directory with many other *jpg* files.

I want to put this in a central Python file to import and use it in different python files.

```py
from HelperRoutines import get_the_MC_list
```

Then I call it in one of my files, e.g.:

```py
if os.path.isdir(StartDirPath) == True:
    OutDirPath = os.path.join(OutDirectory,MoveDir)
    FileInList = get_the_MC_list(StartDirPath)
    print(len(FileInList), MoveDir)
```

When I have my function defined in my `helperfunctions.py`, and call it from the python file I am running, I get the following error:

```py
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

However, if I have my function defined in the python file I am currently running, it works fine.

Any thoughts?

I'm running *Python 3.10.1* on *MacOS 12.3*

Comment: `print(type(get_the_MC_list))`  to chek please. Perhaps there is an import error problem due to naming

Comment: I think you'll want to go through the official documentation on [Modules and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).